# last line in this jQuery code doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have this code set up and everything works except the last line for some reason.

```
function getBlogs(element, url, limit, feed){
    jQuery(element).load(url+ ' .blog_list .module_body:lt('+ limit+ ')', function(){
        jQuery(this).prepend("<a class='home-rss' href='"+ feed+ "'></a>");
        jQuery(this).append("<a class='view-all-blogs' href='"+ url+"'>View More &raquo;</a>");
        // ** The following line isn't working: **
        jQuery(".tab-container .module_body .postbody").last("a").addClass("continue-link");
    });
}

var blogUrl = 'http://mysite.com/blog/list';
var feedUrl = '/profiles/blog/feed';
getBlogs('#all-blogs', blogUrl, 5, feedUrl);
getBlogs('#feat-blogs', blogUrl+ '?tag=featured', 5, feedUrl+ '?promoted=1');

jQuery(".tab_content").hide();
jQuery("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
jQuery(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

//On Click Event
jQuery("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    jQuery("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    jQuery(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    jQuery(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

    var activeTab = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    jQuery(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
    return false;
});

jQuery("#column1").append("<ul class='tabs'><li class='news'><a href='#all-blogs'>News</a></li><li class='featured-blogs'><a href='#feat-blogs'>Featured Blogs</a></li></ul><div class='tab_container'><div id='all-blogs' class='tab_content'></div><div id='feat-blogs' class='tab_content'></div></div>");
```

Specifically, the class doesn't get added with this line:

```
jQuery(".tab-container .module_body .postbody").last("a").addClass("continue-link");
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

-edit-
Here's the html affected by it:

```
<div class="postbody">
 <p><a href="link" target="_self"><img width="633" src="image"></a></p>
 <p>Title</p>
 <a href="link">Continue</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML affected by the last line? The problem could just be how that is organised.

Comment: Thanks @sje397, I added the html. Also, I added the rest of the code for the tabs I have set up.

Comment: does it work if you remove the `.tab-container` and `.module_body` selectors from that line?

Comment: @sje397 No, it doesn't. Just tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
jQuery(".tab-container .module_body .postbody").find("a").last().addClass("continue-link");
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/last/), the `last` method doesn't take a selector.

Also not that in some places, you have used the class name `tab_container` and in others, you have used `tab-container`. That won't help.

Comment: @steven - Here's a jsfiddle showing (a variation of) the above code working: http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/TyNKD/